# Для каждого файла в папке создать свою папку с именем файла

Tags: gulp

Собственно, требуется для каждого файла в папке создать свою папку с собственным именем, которое будет таким же, как имя самого файла.

Есть папка с исходниками jade.
В нем без какой-либо вложенности лежат файлы jade.
То есть типа такого:

```
_jade
  forum.jade
  clients.jade
  organisation.jade
```

Всё это - файлы index.html по сути, просто названы так для удобства.
И есть выходная папка для проекта *client*, как итоговая. Вот, что должно получиться:

```
  client
    forum
      index.html // Содержимое forum.jade
    clients
      index.html // Содержимое clients.jade
    organisation
      index.html // Содержимое organisation.jade
```

Моя проблема в том, что я просто не могу найти, как взять имя файла из файла... Поскольку зная имя файла, можно просто указать галпу путь в dest и он сам создаст папку, а ренеймить файлы я уже знаю как. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: [Gulp 3: Потоки Vinyl-FS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBdKplKl_3Q)

Comment: @greybutton спасибо, теперь смогу написать сам)